# Systemd: how to properly restart service/socket

Tags: systemd, services

I have a fairly simple web service using Django and Gunicorn / Uvicorn:

foo.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo service
Requires=foo.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=foo
Group=www-data
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/foo/current/backend
ExecStart=/var/lib/foo/.local/bin/poetry run gunicorn \
--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=foo.settings \
--capture-output \
--log-level info \
--bind unix:/run/foo.sock \
--worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
--workers 4 \
foo.asgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

foo.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/foo.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

I have both the service enabled and started. When I re-deploy the application, I'm migrating DB and doing other stuff, during that time I need the app to be offline. But when I issue:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart foo.service
```

I get this message

```
Warning: Stopping foo.service, but it can still be activated by:
  foo.socket
```

Am I supposed to restart the socket instead? Disable the service and just leave the socket enabled? (The socket is in turn used by nginx). What's the best practice here? I don't want the service to be activated via socket while I'm migrating the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three options:

1. Start/stop both units together.  This is not the best solution because it requires you to remember to do this.

```
sudo systemctl stop foo.{service,socket}
```

2. Manage the service only.  This requires you to:

   - drop the `[Install]` section of the socket.  That isn't needed because the service already `Requires=` the socket. When the service is started, the socket will be too.
   - Add `PartOf=foo.service` to the socket's `[Unit]` section.  This means when `foo.service` is stopped or restarted, that command is propagated to the socket.

```
# foo.service
[Unit]
Requires=foo.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

#foo.socket
[Unit]
PartOf=foo.service
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/foo.sock
```

Now you can `sudo systemctl {restart,stop,start} foo.service` and the socket will always be in sync.

3. Manage the socket only.  I prefer this option because the service only starts running when data arrives on the socket.  To do this:

   - Remove `Requires=` from the service.  Since we are not starting the service directly, it doesn't need this.
   - Remove the `[Install]` section from the service.  We will rely on the socket instead.
   - Add `PartOf=foo.socket` to the service's `[Unit]` section.  This might not be needed if your application exits on `EOF` on stdin or stdout.
   - Add `StandardInput=socket` to the `[Service]` section of your service.  This isn't strictly necessary, but it will make `systemctl start foo.service` fail if the socket isn't started.

```
# foo.service
[Unit]
PartOf=foo.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
StandardInput=socket
...


#foo.socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/foo.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```